# VMs restarted during backup job - due to VM patching

Tags: virtual-machines, patch-management

I wonder what will happen when the VMs are restarted while backup is running ?

Our backup runs almost 12 hrs at night. And at that time, we are also going to apply the patches and reboot the VMs. I am not sure what will happen if the backup is running and we reboot the VM.

We are using VCB for our snapshots.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory if you're using snapshots you're fine.

If your backups are really taking 12 hours I'd start looking at adding spool disks to speed them up as that's (obviously) a long time, at least for nightlies, weeklies might be ok.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know VCB is using snapshots to do backups. There shouldn't be any problems rebooting a snapshotted vm.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

If you are backing up the VM store, you should be OK if you are using some kind of snapshotting.  Otherwise you are backing up inconsistent data anyways.

If you are backing the VMs up as if they were real computers, then your backup will probably abort if the VM reboots while the backup is happening.